# Visual Studio 2022 Winforms Designer errors from working VS2019 project

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer, visual-studio-2022, objectlistview

Yesterday I installaed VS2022 and opend an existing Winforms project.
I can build and debug the application, but when I try to open the form in designer, it says:
*"Could not find type 'BrightIdeasSoftware.ObjectListView'. Please make sure that the assembly that contains this type is referenced. If this type is a part of your development project, make sure that the project has been successfully built using settings for your current platform or Any CPU."*

*BrightIdeasSoftware.ObjectListView* is a project inside my solution and builds, and it has the same target plattform. In VS2019 I can open the form in designer without problems.

Has anyone an idea what the problem could be?

Comment: It works just fine when adding the control from the Nuget package.  So that's one basic way to get ahead.  "Target platform" is notoriously misunderstood, and that matters for VS2022, the designer now runs in 64-bit mode.  Right-click the ObjectListView project in the Solution Explorer window > Properties > Build tab.  Ensure that "Target platform" = AnyCPU and "Prefer 32-bit" is unticked.

Comment: Yes, I tried it also that way and it works now. Thank you @HansPassant. Strange anyway...

Comment: @HansPassant's comment should be promoted to an answer and Hans should get the Accepted Answer credit.